# `toFixed()` is not working properly for some numbers

Tags: javascript

`Number#toFixed()` is not working properly for some numbers.
Eg:-

```
7.795.toFixed(2) 
//-> 7.79                  #Instead it should display 7.80

8.895.toFixed(2)
//-> 8.89                  #Instead it should display 8.90

1.105.toFixed(2) 
//-> 1.10                  #Instead it should display 1.11

55.305.toFixed(2) 
//-> 55.30                 #Instead it should display 55.31
```

Please provide me with a solution to this problem.

Comment: `toFixed()` is a javascript method - nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a jQuery error, this is the behavior of default Javascript.

A solution can be:

```
(Math.round(55.305 * 100) / 100) = 55.31
```

Comment: **(Math.round(9.995 * 100) / 100) = 9.99  # Instead it should display 100.**

Comment: If you don't want any numbers behind comma. Just use `Math.round(9.995)`

Answer (score 2):

```
function round_float(x,n){
  if(!parseInt(n))
    var n=0;
  if(!parseFloat(x))
    return false;
  return Math.round(x*Math.pow(10,n))/Math.pow(10,n);
}
round_float(1.105,2).toFixed(2);
```

//result :  1.11